# how to make border when hover on menu element

Tags: css

I want to make border around hovered menu element, i have a problem that when i hover the rest menu elements is moving right, since i used padding, how can i make it stay fixed?

```css
.menu ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.menu li {
  line-height: 152px;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding-left: 40px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.menu a {
  color: #000;
}

.menu li a.active {
  color: #4bcaff;
}

.menu li a:hover {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="active">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: why you want padding on hover .remove `padding ` `a:hover`

Comment: how then can i apply spacing between border and a element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set the `padding` on the regular state of the `<a>` element instead of `:hover`. The `:hover` state inherits the `padding` of the regular state. So the `padding` and "big" flickering issue should be gone.

To avoid a "small" flickering issue on the `:hover` state, caused by the additional border you have to set a not visible border (with same `border-width`) to the regular state.

**See the following solution, using the "placeholder-border" and `border`:**

```css
.menu ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 152px;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding-left: 40px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.menu a {
  color: #000;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}
.menu li a.active {
  color: #4bcaff;
}
.menu li a:hover {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<nav class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="active">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

**Another solution without the "placeholder-border" and `border`, using `box-shadow`:**

```css
.menu ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 152px;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding-left: 40px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.menu a {
  color: #000;
  padding: 5px;
}
.menu li a.active {
  color: #4bcaff;
}
.menu li a:hover {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 1px rgba(255,0,0,1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 1px rgba(255,0,0,1);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 1px rgba(255,0,0,1);
}
```

```html
<nav class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="active">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: setting up an invisible border is the perfect solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**I suggest three changes** (the third is what really solves your issue):

1. `box-sizing: border-box` for all elements - makes styling more consistent and intuitive.
2. Remove `padding` and instead add `margin` for the `li` elements. Remember that `padding` is additional space from the content to the border of the element; `margin` however is additional space *outside* the border so it is a better fit to put some space between items.
3. Add the `padding` for your `a` elements not only on hover, but also for their regular state; then on hover, make the padding 1px smaller in order to level the added 1px border.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.menu ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.menu li {
  line-height: 152px;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.menu a {
  color: #000;
  padding: 5px;
}

.menu li a.active {
  color: #4bcaff;
}

.menu li a:hover {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="active">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```